# sIFR class font colour change?

Tags: sifr3

going crazy now after so many hours at the screen...

got this site - http://www.laureleroch.com - to get finished asap...

got this code half working but can't get the font colour of the .sub_title class to change... tried everything I can think of, trawled the net for the last 90 mins...stuck. See how the word 'Welcome.' is displaying in a different colour to the one I'm trying to test with? should be coming up in #006600...but no :( Seems to still be taking it's color setting from the flash movie??!! Dunno. Some clear direction would be really, really appreciated...got father-in-law arriving tomorrow aswell - who needs it!?

Oops, sorry for the sidetrack - def too many hours at the screen!

Ok, so...

**in sifr-config.js...**

```
    sIFR.replace(officina, {
      selector: '.sub_title,.menu_class a,.menu_class a:hover,.menu_class,',
      css: [
            '.sIFR-root {background: transparent;}',
            '.menu_class a {color: #493A19; text-decoration: none;}',
            '.menu_class a:hover {color: #7C6D45; text-decoration: none;}',
            '.sub_title {color: #006600; text-decoration: none;}',
            ],
      wmode: 'transparent',    
});
```

**in leroch_styles.css...**

```
.menu_class {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.menu_class a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.menu_class a:hover {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.sub_title {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

**in sifr.css...**

```
@media screen {
  /* Example:
  .sIFR-active h1 {
    font-family: Verdana;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  */
}
.sIFR-active sub_title {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: transparent;
}
.sIFR-active menu_class {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Thanks muchly...

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the selectors in "replace" is wrong, look here for an example how it should look like: http://www.3point7designs.com/blog/2006/08/easy-sifr-3-setup/

I think you could also try to change the color here:

```
.sub_title {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
color: #006600;
}
```